# Deleting a incorrectly set SVN mergeinfo manually created with GIT-SVN

Tags: svn

How do I delete a incorrectly set SVN mergeinfo from SVN? I made the mistake of creating a custom mergeinfo... SVN now reports the dreaded

```
svn: E200020: Pathname not terminated by ':'
```

error. Is there a way to delete a specific mergeinfo from SVN? All I was able to find was a way to delete all mergeinfos.

SVN propget reports:

```
cd svn
svn propget svn:mergeinfo --depth=infinity | grep -v :
trunk - /PROJECT/branches/my_branch
```

I can't seem to delete it:

```
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo "/PROJECT/branches/my_branch"
svn: E155007: '/PROJECT/branches/my_branch' is not a working copy
```

We used `svn propedit` to edit the svn mergeinfo:

```
svn propedit trunk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) is a property on your `svn` directory, so you need to delete it from there and then commit it:

```
cd svn
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo 
svn commit -m "Deleting bad mergeinfo"
```

The `/PROJECT/branches/my_branch` indicates that revisions were merged into your working copy located in the `svn` folder from `my_branch`.

Comment: That's actually the way we went. It turns out that I deleted a couple of mergeinfo properties in SVN... We did a `svn proplist` on an earlier revision and a `svn propedit` on the current revision to add the information again.